# HTML5 page link is disabled

Tags: html

The 'view this' link on the following page doesn't work and for the life of me i can't work out why?

http://www.johnnyno.co.uk/index_old.html

The HTML for the link on the site is

```
<a href="http://www.stylistpick.com/shoes/">view this</a>
```

But clicking on it does't do anything - just search for "view this" and try to click it

Thanks!

Comment: Please assemble your question a little better. Where is the link? Show us some code. Please update your question.

Comment: Nice way to try and get some visits to your site. Relevant code goes here in your post or else we're not even bothering to help you with that.

Comment: It works when I disable JavaScript, so something is preventing the default action.

Comment: you may be preventing default somewhere in your jquery

Answer (score 3):

That's because you're handling all clicks in the container with this code:

```
$('.thumbnails-portfolio li').on('click touchend', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).find('.page').length > 0){
        AnimateLightBox($(this));
    }
});
```

You should add a selector to filter the clicks on the thumbnail only:

```
$('.thumbnails-portfolio li').on('click touchend', '.thumbnail', function(e){...
```